# What design pattern to apply when I receive a message before I actually listen to it

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost-asio, messaging

I had designed a kind of Publish/Subscribe Observer/Listener design pattern, where my business system was subscribing to listen to one type of message A, and then unsubscribing so as to subscribe for listening to another type of message B.

The problem is that I reveice message A and B really shorlty one after the other, so fastly that my system has not yet subscribed to listen to B messages when the B message is already received: Consequence is, with my current system my listener is never notified.

I was thinking about using a queue to store all incoming messages, and consume them after listeners have been notified.

But I was wondering if there are common implementations for such an issue.

Comment: Is it not possible to listen to both messages at the same time?

Comment: My state machine is mono thread, and it must finish all the message A effects before it is ready to accept another message and handle it.

Comment: From what you said, I assume your messages are on a different thread than your business system. Have your threads post all messages to a queue in your business system. Look at [boost::io_service::post](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html)

Comment: The Poco library offers notifications, that seem to be exactly what you are describing, and they are using a priority queue (http://pocoproject.org/slides/090-NotificationsEvents.pdf)